# Interactive ways to learn Latin?

Tags: classical-latin

Do you have any idea how to learn Latin interactively? It is really mundane to just read from a book and look up words in the dictionary.

Comment: I've mentioned before the National Archive on-line Latin Course. It isn't interactive; but there is immediate feed-back on exercises, and original documents are digitised for teaching material and tests, At two levels - absolute beginners and advanced.

Answer (score 3):

I only tried the trial version, but Rosetta Stone has a [Latin module](http://www.rosettastone.com/learn-latin).

If you've never used Rosetta Stone, it's essentially learning through pictures and sounds rather than going through a grammar book.

[image: Rosetta Stone Latin]

Pictures and words are repeated over and over again until you learn it. As I said, I only used a trial version, so I do not know how they deal tenses or other complex grammar, but it should be enough to get your foot in the door.

Answer (score 2):

If by any chance you know Spanish, [this website](http://www.luduslitterarius.net/) is a great interactive tool. It has plenty of exercises, nicely presented, using Flash. You select the exercises, use the mouse and keyboard to interact with it, and get immediate feedback on your result, all amid a colorful platform. And free!

For example, this is the screen for verb conjugation:

[image]

You can select every type of mode and time. Even more, it adjusts the difficulty depending on your answers.

The best though is its own version (with animation and sounds) of the [Hangman game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangman_(game)). You can see below (I lost):

[image]